# Secure text input

Tags: swift, macos, security

In my app there is a place where the user can enter in some sensitive information. I'm using a `NSSecureTextField` for that.

However, `NSSecureTextField` just uses a plain `String` to store its contents. This poses an issue because I would like to destroy that `String` instance, but that is impossible because strings are immutable.

When the user finishes typing his password, there would probably be 10+ instances of that password in memory.

Is there any way to somehow have a more secure method of entering text?

Comment: "that is impossible because strings are immutable"  How so?

Comment: @ElTomato Well assuming the user types in a bunch of characters, than every single time that happens then a new string has to be created

Comment: I have no idea about the issue that you are referring to.  Please show some lines of code to make your point.

Comment: Im trying to say how would you clear and zero out the password string in memory?

Comment: @ElTomato See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8881291/3141234 for comparison

Comment: @AudioPlayer1234 Fundamentally, `String` isn't well-suited to this task. Like you said, it's immutable, but it's also very easily copy-able. Ideally, if Swift had move-only types, a purpose-specific, erasable string type could be made that has singular ownership. However, `NSSecureTextField` forces you to use `NSString`, so you don't really have a choice.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess ill just deal with it then

Comment: Is the text visible and editable?